# Core data doesn't display data / nil relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an IOS application that uses core data. I have quite a complex model (10+ entities) and everything is working well... most of the time. I really need some help in tracking down the root cause of a couple of issues or some general pointers into what could be causing the issues and what to look for.

A couple of end users are experiencing issues. There are 2 issues both relating to core data. They both only seem to appear after a while (hours/days after first use).

The first is I am retrieving a list of call objects to an array to generate JSON for them. this code works perfectly fine, but one or two users after a while start getting an error. the call entity has a relationship to a callstatus object - the relationship is called `statusForCall`. There is no way for the user to set this relationship to `nil`. The relationship is defineltly set initially when the call entity is generated. the status is set and happy after the initial save the user has checked this). however one times all call objects `statusForCall` relationship is returning `nil`.

installing the app back over the top seems to fix this issue (the data doesn't get changed doing this, but the relationship magiacally works again).

the second issues I have is slightly different. I am retrieving a list of call objects through a `NSFetchedResultsController` for a table view. this has a simple filter applied. The table view is blank. if I apply the original filter AND additional filter the data is returned. The initial filter is `closedDate` is not `nil`. This leaves the tableview blank, even though there are matching records. If I change the filter to `closedDate` is not `nil` and `scheduledDate` is not `nil` then it returns data to the tableview even thought the filter is the same as the original, but with an ADDED condition.

again this issue is only for a couple of users. It doesn't happen straight waway and can take hours/days to start.

strangely the tableview issue seems to solve itself again after a while.

I have seen suggestions this behaviour could be being casued by caching, but have specified `nil` as the cachename for the fetch requests.

the fact that I am 99% sure that the data is correct is the bit I don't understand.

the first issue with the `stausForCall` being `nil` - I understand that CD might not give you the data until you access a property of the relationship., bbut I am doing this. the line that errors is:

```
[dict setObject:aCall.statsuForCall.statusID forKey:@"statusID"];
```

so I am accessing a property.

as I say this relationship cannot be set to `nil` by the user and there is no code to alter the relationship once the call object has been initially created.

the fact that it only happens after a period of time also confuses me.

the table view not giving me data back is also a bit random. this also happened on 2 different view controllers accessing different objects in CD. but without changing the code or the application the user reported that it started working again after a few hours or not working.

can the CD store be corrupt? can it be a caching issue? how can I test that the underlying data is actually OK?

the biggest issue is that when the users report an issue - if I add some debug code to the build and get them to overwrite their application the issues disappear instantly. the code and data does not change, I have add some debug alerts.

again is this due to core data thinking it's migrating data and "fixing" whatever issue has manifested?

i'm quite confused by this (as you can probably tell!!)

code for the fetch request - pleas note there is an action button with 2 choices for the user - "open jobs" which works 99.999999% of the time but then stops for a user after an undefined period of time. When this first filter is not working the second one still does.

```
[self changeTitle];
NSFetchRequest *request=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Call"];
NSString *sectionKeyPathName=nil;

NSString *searchPre=self.searchBar.text;

// self.showIndex = YES;
if ([self.mode isEqualToString:@"OPEN JOBS"])
{




    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" closedDate = nil and assignedToCall==YES"];


    if ([self.searchBar.text length]>0)
    {
        NSPredicate * newCondition = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(shortAddress CONTAINS[cd] %@ or address CONTAINS[cd] %@ or lettingArea CONTAINS[cd] %@  or postCode CONTAINS[cd] %@ or woRef CONTAINS[cd] %@)",searchPre,searchPre,searchPre,searchPre,searchPre];
        NSPredicate * newPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:request.predicate, newCondition, nil]];
        request.predicate = newPredicate;
    }



    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"hasAppointmentForOrderBy" ascending:NO ];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateScheduled" ascending:YES ];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor3 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scheduledTime" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

   NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor4 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateDue" ascending:YES ];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor2,sortDescriptor3,sortDescriptor4, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    sectionKeyPathName=@"sectionHeaderSortScheduledOrNot";
}
if ([self.mode isEqualToString:@"TODAY'S JOBS (ONLY)"])
{


    NSDateComponents* comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate* todayNoTime = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];


    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dateDue = %@  or dateScheduled = %@)  and closedDate = nil and assignedToCall==YES",todayNoTime,todayNoTime];


    if ([self.searchBar.text length]>0)
    {
        NSPredicate * newCondition = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(shortAddress CONTAINS[cd] %@ or address CONTAINS[cd] %@ or lettingArea CONTAINS[cd] %@  or postCode CONTAINS[cd] %@ or woRef CONTAINS[cd] %@)",searchPre,searchPre,searchPre,searchPre,searchPre];
        NSPredicate * newPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:request.predicate, newCondition, nil]];
        request.predicate = newPredicate;
    }


    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"shortAddress" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    sectionKeyPathName=@"lettingArea";
}

self.currentFilter= request.predicate;


[self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    self.fetchedResultsController =[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc ] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:sectionKeyPathName cacheName:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check

- The cache name of your fetched results controller. I recommend setting it to `nil`.
- The predicate checking for `NULL`. Maybe you should post this code.

Answer (score 0):

this was caused by a relationship being set to cascade delete. it was from the many end to the one end - meaning that the one end got deleted (this was a bit alien coming form a SQL environment here this would not be allowed because of referential integrity)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Tried to delete data and put it again to the list of project files?

Comment: It is a proposal.